# Normalising data on rows, using user defined function, with NA values in rows

Tags: r, apply, na

I'm trying to do a general feature scaling [0.1,0.9] on the rows of a dataframe. (let's call it Market) . Some columns have NA values, which I'd like to ignore but not omitted from processing. I use apply to perform the operation but every row that has even one NA value becomes all NA's in the result. 
here is an example:

this is my function that normalises row entries `[0.1, 0.9]`

`Norm <- function(x) 0.1+(x-min(x))*0.8/(max(x)-min(x))`

the Market data frame contains a few columns that are NOT numeric 
(the first four columns), so i only use the columns [5:16] to do calculations

here is a snapshot of the first 15 rows of dataframe Market[1:15, 5:16]

```
     Jan   Feb   Mar   Apr   May   Jun   Jul   Aug   Sep   Oct   Nov  Dec
1     NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA  1.46  1.20  1.20    NA   NA
2     NA 41.67 40.00 40.00    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA   NA
3     NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA 12.00 12.00    NA    NA   NA
4  57.50    NA 31.11 41.00 54.64 55.00 55.00 55.00 55.00 53.00 47.00 33.0
5  12.17  9.17    NA    NA    NA    NA 11.00 11.00 10.22    NA    NA   NA
6  15.67 30.00 30.00 40.00 50.94    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA 62.33 56.5
7  12.05 13.50    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA  7.50  8.83   NA
8     NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA 10.00  6.13    NA    NA   NA
9   1.90    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA  2.00  2.00    NA  1.88  1.51  1.7
10  2.00  1.91  1.81  1.81  1.85  2.00  2.00  2.05  2.09  1.90    NA   NA
11 24.11 29.17 35.00 35.00 35.00 30.45 30.00 29.67 24.09 20.00 20.00 23.0
12    NA 27.50 32.50 35.00    NA    NA 33.88 23.00    NA    NA 21.33 20.0
13 27.00 33.75    NA 24.50 28.00    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA   NA
14    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA 33.63 23.50    NA    NA    NA   NA
15 23.67 27.33 27.55 26.00 30.71 27.83    NA    NA    NA    NA 24.00 24.0
```

what i would like to do is to normalise each row [0.1,0.9] with the data available in each row. that is, the result SHOULD be:

```
     Jan   Feb   Mar   Apr   May   Jun   Jul   Aug   Sep   Oct   Nov  Dec
1     NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA  0.90  0.10  0.10    NA   NA
2     NA  0.90  0.10  0.10    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA   NA
3     NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA   NA
4   0.90    NA   0.10  0.40  0.81  0.82  0.82  0.82  0.82  0.76  0.58  0.16
5  ...
6  ...
7  ...
8  ...  
9  ... 
10  0.64   0.38  0.10  0.10  0.21  0.64  0.64  0.78  0.90  0.36   NA   NA 
11  0.32   0.59  0.90  0.90  0.90  0.66  0.63  0.62  0.32  0.10  0.10 0.26
12  ...
13  ...
14    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA   0.90  0.10   NA    NA    NA   NA
15  0.10   0.52  0.54  0.36  0.90  0.57   NA    NA    NA    NA   0.14 0.14
```

So, while NA values are ignored, they are not omitted in each row.
But when i use the following command, using apply, all rows become NA, except for the 11th row, where there is no NA entry.

Here is the apply command i use trying to get the above results, but to no avail:

`Market_normed <- data.frame(t(apply(Market[5:16], 1, Norm)`

This is the UNWANTED result i get:

Market2012_nom[1:15, ]

```
      Jan       Feb Mar Apr May       Jun       Jul       Aug       Sep Oct Nov  Dec
1      NA        NA  NA  NA  NA        NA        NA        NA        NA  NA  NA   NA
2      NA        NA  NA  NA  NA        NA        NA        NA        NA  NA  NA   NA
3      NA        NA  NA  NA  NA        NA        NA        NA        NA  NA  NA   NA
4      NA        NA  NA  NA  NA        NA        NA        NA        NA  NA  NA   NA
5      NA        NA  NA  NA  NA        NA        NA        NA        NA  NA  NA   NA
6      NA        NA  NA  NA  NA        NA        NA        NA        NA  NA  NA   NA
7      NA        NA  NA  NA  NA        NA        NA        NA        NA  NA  NA   NA
8      NA        NA  NA  NA  NA        NA        NA        NA        NA  NA  NA   NA
9      NA        NA  NA  NA  NA        NA        NA        NA        NA  NA  NA   NA
10     NA        NA  NA  NA  NA        NA        NA        NA        NA  NA  NA   NA
11 0.3192 0.5890667 0.9 0.9 0.9 0.6573333 0.6333333 0.6157333 0.3181333 0.1 0.1 0.26
12     NA        NA  NA  NA  NA        NA        NA        NA        NA  NA  NA   NA
13     NA        NA  NA  NA  NA        NA        NA        NA        NA  NA  NA   NA
14     NA        NA  NA  NA  NA        NA        NA        NA        NA  NA  NA   NA
15     NA        NA  NA  NA  NA        NA        NA        NA        NA  NA  NA   NA
```

I have a feeling i either need to change the way i use apply or the way i define my function. any help would be so greatly appreciated.

Comment: More information: Please note that I added na.rm = TRUE to the min and max functions in my function and that didn't change anything.

Answer (score 1):

`min` and `max` both have a `na.rm=` option to ignore missing values.

eg

```
min(x, na.rm=TRUE)
```

When I use

```
 Norm <- function(x) 0.1+(x-min(x, na.rm=T))*0.8/(max(x, na.rm=T)-min(x, na.rm=T))
```

I get:

```
    Jan  Feb  Mar  Apr  May  Jun  Jul  Aug  Sep  Oct  Nov  Dec
1    NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA 0.90 0.10 0.10   NA   NA
2    NA 0.90 0.10 0.10   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
3    NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA  NaN  NaN   NA   NA   NA
4  0.90   NA 0.10 0.40 0.81 0.82 0.82 0.82 0.82 0.76 0.58 0.16
5  0.90 0.10   NA   NA   NA   NA 0.59 0.59 0.38   NA   NA   NA
6  0.10 0.35 0.35 0.52 0.70   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA 0.90 0.80
7  0.71 0.90   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA 0.10 0.28   NA
8    NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA 0.90 0.10   NA   NA   NA
9  0.74   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA 0.90 0.90   NA 0.70 0.10 0.41
10 0.64 0.39 0.10 0.10 0.21 0.64 0.64 0.79 0.90 0.36   NA   NA
11 0.32 0.59 0.90 0.90 0.90 0.66 0.63 0.62 0.32 0.10 0.10 0.26
12   NA 0.50 0.77 0.90   NA   NA 0.84 0.26   NA   NA 0.17 0.10
13 0.32 0.90   NA 0.10 0.40   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
14   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA 0.90 0.10   NA   NA   NA   NA
15 0.10 0.52 0.54 0.36 0.90 0.57   NA   NA   NA   NA 0.14 0.14
```

Comment: I tried addling na.rm = TRUE to both min and max functions in my function and it didn't change the results.

Comment: Did you try all three? both mins?

Comment: yes, my function is Norm <- function(x)0.1+(x-min(x, na.rm=TRUE))*0.8/(max(x,.na.rm=TRUE)-min(x,na.rm=TRUE))

Comment: Hi there, I looked again and it seems that i had a . somewhere in my function that made it not work. It is now working. thank you so much for your help!!!!